# slow replay in box2d

Tags: box2d

I am trying to show a slow replay of a particular event in my box2d game. This event involves objects moving, rotating, colliding and getting destroyed based on health.

What I have done is that i store the state of all objects in my world just before the event starts and restore them when the event finishes so that everything can happen all over again. As I want this replay to be slower, I am passing a fraction of the actual time passed to my world update function. All movements and objects are fine except for collision handling and some objects that were destroyed in the original run survive in the replay and vice versa.

Can this thing actually be done correctly in theory with box2d or I am wasting time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most important thing is to keep the time step length the same for both runs. To make it appear slow you can interpolate the positions for rendering.
Box2D keeps some internal state to help with efficiency and I don't think you can completely nullify this by resetting the positions and velocities back to the stored state and running it again.

If the slow-mo is not too long, I would probably just run the simulation only once and record the positions of everything in every step, and use that to render both the slow-mo and the full speed run. For example if the slow-mo is three seconds long and you're running at 60fps, as soon as you want a slow-mo scene, Step() the world by 180 steps (without rendering) and store the position of everything in an array or something. Then you can render the slow-mo by interpolating the positions in the array at whatever speed you like, forward or backwards :) When the slow-mo scene is done, throw away the array and continue as normal. The drawback is if you have a large world it could take a noticeable amount of time to run the 180 steps.

Comment: The world is large and the event is long. I dont think recording the positions and rotations for all frames would be feasible. And if I slow it down too much, it will have discontinuous motion. Not cool.

Comment: That's why you would interpolate the positions when rendering. Sounds like tough one though if the world is large...

Answer (score 0):

iforce2d is right. The best way of doing replay is to record all the positions. Because even if you give same inputs to box2d there's a possibility of different output.